# Retrofit 2 file upload does not attach file

Tags: android, file-upload, asp.net-core, retrofit

I've written a upload action on server using asp core and I've tested that with ARC and files gets received.

[image: Correctness Evidence]

But when I try to upload image with Retrofit, nothing gets send. Even the form is empty:

[image: Fault Occured]

The source Code of interface is here. The interface:

```
public interface QuestionWebService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("questionapi/uploadfiles")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadSync(@Part("fileUpload") RequestBody paramTypedFile);
}
```

and the usage in async task:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


            File fileToSend = new File(params[0]);

//            fileToSend.renameTo()

            RequestBody typedFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), fileToSend);
            Response response = restClient.getQuestionService().uploadSync(typedFile).execute();

            if (response == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "success send server - failed");
                return  false;
            }
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "success send server - 200 status");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "success send server - fail status - " + response.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw new RuntimeException(e);
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage().toString());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Any Idea about what should I try? Where am I Going Wrong.
TG.

Comment: che hame soal deri shuma :D :-P

Comment: retrofit2 with multipart only support part type data

Comment: @Saveen what do you mean by part type data? What is wrong and what should I change?

Comment: OK this is probably dumb so feel free to ignore but why is UploadFiles flagged with the green underline?  I most often see this when I am inheriting a class and I have a method name the same as the class I inherited.  I am just curious why VS has tagged that.

Comment: @Woot - My guess is the green underline is due the function being async, but contains no async (i.e. await) calls.

Comment: @GaryHolland Yes you are right. It's not so important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I don't know the reason about why this code doesn't work but as [this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) says, I changed the:

```
public interface QuestionWebService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("questionapi/uploadfiles")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadSync(@Part("fileUpload") RequestBody paramTypedFile);
}
```

to this one:

```
public interface QuestionWebService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("questionapi/uploadfiles")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadSync(@Part("UserId") RequestBody UserId, @Part("answer") RequestBody answer, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

and the usage from this:

```
RequestBody typedFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), fileToSend);
            Response response = restClient.getQuestionService().uploadSync(typedFile).execute();
```

to this one:

```
// create RequestBody instance from file
            RequestBody requestFile =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), fileToSend);

            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            MultipartBody.Part body =
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileUpload", fileToSend.getName(), requestFile);
RequestBody userId =
                    RequestBody.create(
                            MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), userIdString);

            // add another part within the multipart request
            String answerString = "hello, this is answer speaking";
            RequestBody answer =
                    RequestBody.create(
                            MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), answerString);

            Response response = restClient.getQuestionService().uploadSync(userId, answer, body).execute();
```

and now every thing goes right!!!
I hope this will the others encounter same problem.

Now the data on server is a form with 2 fields, UserId and Answer, and a file named fileUpload.
TG.